# How can I create custom records with suitescript in netsuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suite

```
var recExpense = nlapiCreateRecord("customrecord_expense");
recExpense.setFieldValue(1028,"3223");//employee number
nlapiSubmitRecord(recExpense);
```

I just wrote that simple code to create a new custom record but after the execution just a blank record is being created `setFieldValue` method is not working and it does not update field value.
What am I missing? And how do you create custom records with SuiteScripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above code didn't work because you have to put the `internal id` of the field you want to update not the record id.

```
var recExpense = nlapiCreateRecord("customrecord_expense");
recExpense.setFieldValue('internalid_of_the_field',"3223");//employee number
nlapiSubmitRecord(recExpense);
```

Note : You can go to your record and just click on the field you want to update a help box will pop up and at the bottom you can get the `internal id` of the field.